# Eclipse Plugin Development: How to drag element from Desktop to custom Node in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am making a drag &  drop Eclipse plugin that can drop elements into custom Nodes in Project Explorer.

So far I am able to drag a file from Project Explorer and drop it into one of my custom Nodes I have added in Project Explorer view.
I have registered `dropAssistant` in plugin.xml and have added `possibleDropTargets`.

However I am having trouble dragging an element from Desktop (System Explorer) to my Nodes in Project Explorer. When the mouse cursor is over one of my Nodes the cursor changes to 'X' mark, meaning that I can not drop the element into it.

Here is my `navigatorContent` in `plugin.xml`

```
<plugin>   
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
      <navigatorContent
            activeByDefault="true"
            id="flashimageviewer.navigatorContent"
            name="BinNavigatorContent"
            contentProvider="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.providers.BinContentProvider"
            labelProvider="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.providers.BinLabelProvider"  >
         <triggerPoints>
                <and>
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                        <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.bin" />
                    </adapt>
                    <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
                </and>                 
         </triggerPoints>     
         <!--  The possbile childredn are not needen when Drag & Drop inside ProjectExplorer    -->          
         <possibleChildren>      
            <or>

             <adapt type="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.model.Node"/> 
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>   
            </or>        
         </possibleChildren>        

         <dropAssistant
              class="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.MyCommonDropAdapterAssistant"
              id="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.myCommonDropAdapterAssistant">

            <!--  The possbile targets are not needen when Drag & Drop inside ProjectExplorer    -->   
           <possibleDropTargets>
               <or>                    
                <and>
                    <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                        <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.bin" />
                    </instanceof>             
                </and>            

               <adapt type="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.model.Node"/>    

               <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
               <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>               
           </or>
           </possibleDropTargets>
       </dropAssistant>

       <!--
       <dragAssistant
         class="com.mycompany.flashimageviewer.MyDragListener"
         viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"/> 
           -->
        <!--
         <enablement>
           <or>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile" /> 
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
                   <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" /> 
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot" /> 
           </or>
          </enablement>       
        -->
      </navigatorContent>
   </extension>
```

And here is my implementation of `CommonDropAdapterAssistant`:

```
public class MyCommonDropAdapterAssistant extends CommonDropAdapterAssistant     {

private static final String VALID_MESSAGE = "This drop is valid";
private static final String INVALID_MESSAGE = "Can not handle this drop";

@Override
public IStatus validateDrop(Object target, int operation, TransferData transferType) {
    IStatus iStatus  = null;
    if(target instanceof Node) {
        iStatus= new Status(IStatus.OK, Util.FLASH_IMAGE_VIEWER_PLUGIN_ID, VALID_MESSAGE );
    }else {
        iStatus = new Status(IStatus.CANCEL, Util.FLASH_IMAGE_VIEWER_PLUGIN_ID,  INVALID_MESSAGE); 
    }
    return iStatus;
}

@Override
public IStatus handleDrop(CommonDropAdapter aDropAdapter, DropTargetEvent aDropTargetEvent, Object aTarget) {

    if (aTarget instanceof Node) {
        final Node targetNode = (Node) aTarget;         
        performOperation(targetNode, aDropTargetEvent, aTarget);    // <-- This method here does the actual moving of the dragged element
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can I add support for dragging an element from System Explorer to my Node in Project Explorer?

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that when hovering an element which I have dragged from Desktop, my overrided method `validateDrop` in  `MyCommonDropAdapterAssistant` is never called.

Comment: Can you post the entire navigatorContent extension declaration?

Comment: Done :) If you ask to more info I will try to provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `CommonDropAdapterAssistant` needs to override the `isSupportedType` method, so as to be considered when handling file drops:

```
public boolean isSupportedType(TransferData aTransferType)
{
    return super.isSupportedType(aTransferType)
            || FileTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(aTransferType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried it myself, but you need to use `<adapt type="org.eclipse.swt.dnd.FileTransfer"/>` in your plugin.xml.

Please see http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html for further documentation.

In your `CommonDropAdapterAssistent` you can can check within `validateDrop` if the dropped file is actually supported with: `FileTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(transferType)`

And to actually perform the drop in your `handleDrop` you can use something like:

```java
boolean success = false;
if(FileTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(transferType)) { 
    String[] files = (String[]) aDropTargetEvent.data; 
    int operations = aDropAdapter.getCurrentOperation(); 
    IFSTreeNode target = (IFSTreeNode) aTarget;
    CommonDnD dnd = new CommonDnD();
    success = dnd.dropFiles(getCommonViewer(), files, operations, target); 
}
```

Comment: I added FileTransfer in xml but it did not help. I forgot to mention that the method ValidateDrop in DropAdapterAssistent is never called when the drag origins from Desktop. 
I can not import IFSTreeNode and CommonDnD classes. Can you tell me from what package are they. 
P.S. I am not making RCP.